# Why didn't king Darius notice that Daniel wasn't eaten straight away?

Tags: daniel

Daniel 6:16-17 (ESV)

> 16 Then the king commanded, and Daniel was brought and cast into the den of lions. The king declared to Daniel, “May your God, whom you serve continually, deliver you!” 17 And a stone was brought and laid on the mouth of the den, and the king sealed it with his own signet and with the signet of his lords, that nothing might be changed concerning Daniel.

Daniel 6:24 (ESV)

> 24 And the king commanded, and those men who had maliciously accused Daniel were brought and cast into the den of lions—they, their children, and their wives. And before they reached the bottom of the den, the lions overpowered them and broke all their bones in pieces.

In Daniel 6 verses 16-17, Daniel is thrown into the pit, and the king and other people  notice that the lions didn’t eat Daniel, but they do notice in verse 24 when the “men who had maliciously accused Daniel” get eaten up immediately. How didn't anyone notice that Daniel wasn't eaten immediately?

Comment: it does not say 'they didn't notice', it doesn't say 'they did notice' it simply makes note the wicked people thrown into the den were eaten straightaway. Maybe they in fact did notice Daniel wasn't.

Comment: But king Darius was surprised next day to see him alive.

Comment: Absolutely he was, I think anyone would be. What I mean by my comment is that lack of mention is not evidence to posit a conclusion. So simply not mentioning surprise, does not mean they were not surprised, it just means it wasn't recorded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have the answer now. King Darius probably didn't want to see Daniel being torn to pieces, but was vaguely hoping that Daniel was kept safe by his God.

> Then, at break of day, the king arose and went in haste to the den of lions. As he came near to the den where Daniel was, he cried out in a tone of anguish. The king declared to Daniel, “O Daniel, servant of the living God, has your God, whom you serve continually, been able to deliver you from the lions?”

But because Daniel wasn't eaten, the king might be wondering if anything was wrong with the lions, so he had a closer look next time.

Comment: It's probably not good form to answer your own question. Setting that aside, I think the problem is in how you are conceiving of a "lion's den". When they describe rolling a stone in front of it it seems to be describing a cave. Once the stone was in place they could not see inside until it was removed. So unless the lions ate Daniel before the stone was there, they would not know. It then intentionally points out that those who accused him were eaten right away, presumably, before the stone was put in place.

Comment: But "And before they reached the bottom of the den, the lions overpowered them and broke all their bones in pieces." Suggests that it is some form of hole in the ground, rather than an ordinary cave.

Comment: Seems like some insightful midrash. :) @P.TJ Btw, there's [no problem with "selfies"](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) (and see onward links in that help entry).